# Incrementing an Integer Field in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo

got a simple question, how can I simply increment an Integer Field in Odoo?

If i wanted to do something like this:

```
class exampleModel(models.Model):
    _name = "something"
    var = fields.Integer(default=0)
    
    var = var + 1
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to describe when you want to increment, you just need to define ```self.var += 1``` but again depends on context, can you describe more about what you want to achieve?

Comment: i literally just want to increase the value in the field by 1

Comment: Then use ```default=1```? Why would you set default as 0 but want to increase it by 1? Surely you want an action that increases this on a use case?

Comment: are you looking to create a serial number for each instance of the model / record ?

Comment: Yeah, but I've figured it out, i mistook the field defined in the class as a field in the actual record. I was under the assumption that the classes were instantiated somewhere and that I manipulate fields individually, but the objects seem to be instantiated in the record list within the class itself, and can be manipulated from there. To be honest, the Odoo documentation didn't explain that very well.

Also, the answer suggested by @Jack Dane wouldn't work by any stretch of the imagination. It was beyond misguided and elitist at best.

Comment: @blake_won, could you please share your answer, so others can understand if they have the same question.